# What is the best order of arguments for spatially indexed functions of sf (st_intersects, etc.)?

Tags: indexing, r-sf

It is explained on https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2017/06/22/spatial-index.html that "The R tree is constructed on the first argument (`x`), and used to match all geometries on the second argument (`y`) of binary functions". However, it is finally not explained what are the criteria that could guide the user in the choice of the `sf` object to put in the first argument. Are there some rules of thumb for this choice?

Comment: Perhaps you could benchmark a few options and report back?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, with creating spatial indexes you want to start with a larger envelopes that decompose to smaller envelopes. So, if you are extending from that then starting with a geometry with a larger extent then building smaller envelopes from that would match the general schema of how these selections are optimized.